# OS patches list

Tags: linux, patch-management

How can I check installed list of patches on OS separately for critical security plugins and all other updates. I tried "rpm -qa  --last" and "yum list installed" but didn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--changelog` option:

```
rpm -q --changelog kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a redhat or centos release (6 or 7), you can usen openscap scanner to get a status on known vulnerabilities and check if you have the patches installed or not.

Openscap-scanner is included in standard OS repositories (for yum install), you'll just have to download the current  vulnerabilities definitions as described in this page : https://www.open-scap.org/resources/documentation/perform-vulnerability-scan-of-rhel-6-machine/ (the same applies to el7 with definitions in https://www.redhat.com/security/data/oval/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_7.xml )